# How can I use composition of the classes if they have common fields in java?

Tags: java, oop

How can I use composition of the classes if they have common fields
and I want them to be equal?

for ex, I have 3 classes :

class `SwimmingMonster`, `FlyingMonster` and `SwimmAndFlyMonster` which compose `FlyingMonster` and `SwimmingMonster` .
both classes has field `location`.
and I want it to be the same in both objects `objOfFly` and `objOfSwim` in `SwimAndFly` class.

```
class SwimmingMonster{
private int[] location=new int[2];
{location[0]=0;
location[1]=0;}
void swim(int x,int y){
location[0]+=x;
location[1]+=y;}

}


class FlyingMonster{
private int[] location=new int[2];
{location[0]=0;
location[1]=0;}
void fly(int x,int y){
location[0]+=x;
location[1]+=y;}

}
class SwimAndFlyMonster{
private FlyingMonster objOfFly=new FlyingMonster();
private SwimmingMonster objOfSwim=new SwimmingMonster();
void fly(int x,int y){
objOfFly.fly(x,y);
}
void swim(int x,int y){
objOfSwim.swim(x,y);
}

}
```

but the problem here is that I want the field `location` in `objOfSwim` and `objOfFly`
be equals.

so how can I do that?

is the only solution is to create a setter and getter for location in each class and do this ↓ ?

```
    void fly(int x,int y){
    objOfFly.fly(x,y);
    objOfSwim.set(objOfFly.get(location));
    }
    void swim(int x,int y){
    objOfSwim.swim(x,y);
    objOfFly.set(objOfSwim.get(location));
    }
```

Comment: Reassign one of the object's array to the other: `objOfFly.loc = objOfMove.loc`. (You will have to make a setter since the field is private).

Comment: i have 3 types of monsters.
one can fly and one can move and the other can fly and move

Comment: it's an alternative of multiple inheritance  . here i want to use all the methods and fields  in the 2 classes without copy them . i know in this example the fly and swim method have the same code in this example , but it will not be the same in reality , and i dont want to copy and past them  in the FlyAndSwimmMonster  .

Comment: Assume we understand the concept of composition. It doesn't necessarily lend well in this situation because you're duplicating data. Eg, both of your monster fields have a "location".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I could see this being a composition problem. You could have different actions.

```
Monster{
   int[] location;
}
```

Your actions:

```
SwimAction{
    public void swim(Monster m, int x, int y){
        //whatever you do to update the location.
        m.location[0] += x;
        m.location[1] += y;
    }
}
```

Then a swim monster.

```
SwimMonster{
    Monster base;
    SwimAction swimAction;
    public void swim( int x, int y ){
        swimAction.swim(base, x, y);
    }
}
```

Similarly you could compose more actions.

```
SwimFlyMonster{
    Monster base;
    SwimAction s;
    FlyAction f;
    public void swim(int x, int y){
        s.swim(base, x, y);
    }
    public void fly(int x, int y){
        f.fly(base, x, y);
    }
}
```